# What is the purpose of the `withFdSocket sock setCloseOnExecIfNeeded` call in Network.Socket example?

Tags: sockets, haskell, tcp, network-programming

In the Network.Socket package, there is an echo server example. In the echo server, a call to `withFdSocket sock setCloseOnExecIfNeeded` is made just before actually binding to the socket. The relevant function is below:

```hs
    open :: AddrInfo -> IO Socket
    open addr = E.bracketOnError (openSocket addr) close $ \sock -> do
        setSocketOption sock ReuseAddr 1
        withFdSocket sock setCloseOnExecIfNeeded
        bind sock $ addrAddress addr
        listen sock 1024
        return sock
```

The full example can be found on the [Network.Socket package documentation](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/network-3.1.2.7/docs/Network-Socket.html#v:bind).

What is the purpose of this call? It's my understanding that `withFdSocket` creates a file descriptor associated with the socket, and `setCloseOnExecIfNeeded` sets the CLOEXEC flag on the descriptor. However this descriptor is immediately 'discarded' and nothing is done with it.

Am I confused that the file descriptor always exists and `withFdSocket` just provides this existing descriptor, which we have to update with the flag in order for the socket to close when the program exits?

Comment: it doesn't create a file descriptor. It *gets the* file descriptor

Comment: Ah ok that definitely clarifies why it was called. Now I need to fully understand why CLOEXEC is necessary here. Thank you!

Comment: Not sure about why CLOEXEC is set here. Intuitively, unless you plan to (fork and) `exec` later on it is pointless (?)

Comment: Yeah from what little I can gather it seems like leaving descriptors open when using "the `exec` family of functions" (not that I know what that is) is so dangerous you might as well set CLOEXEC to be extra safe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`withFdSocket` does not create an `Fd`; it just reads the one already stored inside the socket data structure.